# Pronunciation of sound /ʌ/

Tags: pronunciation

I'm learning English and today my question is pronunciation. I'm learning sound /ʌ/ just now. Can you listen to my voice record and tell it correct or no?
https://www.speakpipe.com/voice-recorder/msg/apa9eccvvh09ttws

Comment: the word on the tape is "rub" and "nut"

Comment: This question should be on English Language Learners rather than on this channel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My take:

"rug" sounds pretty good, but "nut" is shifting slightly toward the /a/ vowel like in "not."

Comment: thank you  https://www.speakpipe.com/voice-recorder/msg/2uqqsv107msvhyxq is this better?

Comment: Sounds better. Practice with the front lax vowels:  <knit> and <net>. Maybe it will be easier to stay relaxed for <nut>.